# scipy: How do I use weibull_min.pdf?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, probability, distribution

I'm finding `scipy`'s `weibull_min` `pdf` function unintuitive and hard to use. I want to generate a weibull PDF with scale=30 and shape=2.5. This is what that is supposed to look like:[image][image]

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import weibull_max, uniform
import numpy as np
aoas = np.linspace(0, 8, 1000)
speeds = np.linspace(1, 80, 1000)
plt.fill_between(speeds, speeds * 0, weibull_max.pdf(speeds, 2.5, 30), facecolor='k')
plt.ylabel('Probability Density')
plt.savefig('speedDist.pdf')
plt.clf()
```

[image]

Of course, my code is wrong. The documentation says that `weibull_min` expects `pdf(x, c, loc=0, scale=1)`, where `x` are quantiles, `c` is the shape factor, and `scale` is the scale factor. But, when I change my code to `weibull_max.pdf(speeds, 2.5, 0, 30)`, the output pdf is composed of only zero values. So, I am confusion. How do I generate the desired Weibull PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

- `weibull_min` and `weibull_max` are not the same distribution.  You refer to `weibull_min` in the title and description of the problem, but you use `weibull_max` in the code.  To match the plot that you show, use `weibull_min`.
- The parameters of the `pdf` method are `(x, shape, loc, scale)`.  You wrote `pdf(speeds, 2.5, 30)`, which assigned 30 to the `loc` parameter.  Instead, you should use `pdf(speeds, 2.5, scale=30)`

Here's a variation of your script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import weibull_min


speeds = np.linspace(0, 80, 1000)    
p = weibull_min.pdf(speeds, 2.5, scale=30)

plt.plot(speeds, p, 'b', linewidth=1)
plt.fill_between(speeds, speeds * 0, p, facecolor='b', alpha=0.1)
plt.ylabel('Probability Density')
plt.show()
```

It generates this plot:

[image: plot]